# need to find leaf , inner and root node

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am trying to solve this question which is on hacker rank

I got the desired output but not accepted by hacker rank

**Input :**

[image: Input]

**Output :**

[image: Output]

**My trial 1 :**

```
with tb1 as
(
   select N,P from binary_tree
), tb2 as 
(
   select N,P from binary_tree
)
select t2.N as t2_N,
case 
     when t2.P is null and t1.P is null  and t1.N is null then 'root'
     when t2.P is not null and t1.P is null and t1.N is not null then 'inner'
     ELSE 'leaf'
end as RESULT
from tb2 t2 LEFT JOIN tb1 t1 ON t2.P = t1.N order by t2.N;
```

**My trial 2 :**

```
with tb1 as
(
   select N,P from BST
), tb2 as 
(
   select P from BST
)
select distinct t.* from (select t1.N as tn,
case 
    when t1.N is not null and t2.P is not null and t1.P is null then 'root'
    when t1.N is not null and t2.P is not null and t1.P is not null then 'inner'
    when t1.N is not null and t2.P is null and t1.P is not null then 'leaf'
end as RESULT
from tb1 t1 LEFT JOIN tb2 t2 on t1.N = t2.P) t order by tn;
```

My above querys gives me desired output but not accepted

can some one figure it out why so ?

please explain me how to solve this kind of binary tree questions and any trick to solve it

Comment: Your output has the wrong case - `'leaf'` is not the same as `'Leaf'`, etc. Your second one passes if you fix that. (Though you might want to look at Oracle's hierarchical query syntax; and maybe recursive subquery factoring...)

Comment: @Alex Poole : Thanks bro it worked like charm the second one thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is meant to test your understanding of Oracle "connect by" queries, rather than standard joins. Roots can be identified by `null` parent, leafs are detected by the `connect_by_isleaf` pseudocolumn, and all other nodes are "inner". So, the query can be written like this:

```
select  n,
        case when p is null             then 'Root'
             when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 'Leaf'
             else                            'Inner' end as result
from    binary_tree
start   with p is null
connect by p = prior n
order   by n  --  if needed
;
```

Comment: : Can you please elaborate the connect by not getting step by step

Comment: @yyy62103 - You are trying to answer a question on "hacker rank" - whatever that is. Fine; are you familiar with `connect by` queries? Obviously not. If so, then don't answer the question on "hacker rank" by just posting **my** answer, that is dishonest. If you need to learn about "connect by" queries, that is fine, but this forum is not the proper place for that; this forum is not a school, for users to learn new things, but rather a site where people (presumably qualified) ask their specific questions when they need help with something.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... I haven't used your answer in hacker rank as I solved by using left join on my own. But wanted to know how many different ways it can be solved. I was not aware about  `connect by`.  with your solution I came to know the concept of `connect by level`. I debug your solution and found all node which does not have child are set as 1 and remaining 0 that how you created your answer. For me understanding the  concept was important

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of trial able to write perfect query

**Solution 1 :**

```
with tb1 as
(
   select N,P from BST
), tb2 as 
(
   select P from BST
)
select distinct t.* from (select t1.N as tn,
case 
    when t1.N is not null and t2.P is not null and t1.P is null then 'Root'
    when t1.N is not null and t2.P is not null and t1.P is not null then 'Inner'
    when t1.N is not null and t2.P is null and t1.P is not null then 'Leaf'
end as RESULT
from tb1 t1 LEFT JOIN tb2 t2 on t1.N = t2.P) t order by tn;
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
select 
N,
case 
     when P is null then 'root'
     when P is not null and N in ( select distinct P from BINARY_TREE ) then 'Inner'
     else 'Leaf' end as Result 
from BINARY_TREE order by N;
```

**Solution 3 : Debugged the code of Author** `@mathguy` **who as solved using** `connect by`

**Step 1 : Getting the leaf status**

```
SELECT
    n,
    CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS leaf
FROM
    binary_tree
START WITH
    p IS NULL
CONNECT BY
    p = PRIOR n
ORDER BY
    leaf;
```

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2 : Depending upon the leaf status , defining the case statement**

```
IF P is null -> Root 
else if `1`  -> Leaf
else 'Inner'   


SELECT
    N,
    case 
    when P is null then 'Root'
    when CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 then 'Leaf'
    else 'Inner' end as Result 
FROM
    binary_tree
START WITH
    p IS NULL
CONNECT BY
    P = PRIOR N
ORDER BY
    N;
```

**Output :**

[image: Step 2]